# Multi-Word Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the below issue to consider in one of my worksheets.

Column A contains identifiers from a list, Columns B to F contain various data matching each code.

I have an additional column(M) which contains my own identifiers. What I want to achieve is to match the my identifiers with the ones from the list so I can pull the data from columns B to F according to my codes. These identifiers are mostly the same, with only slight variations.

I've tried with vlookup and wildcard, but I've only been partially successful.

Sample data looks like this with below formula in column M:

[image: sample]

I'm using `=VLOOKUP(A2&"*",mockup2,1,0)` as a formula in "Matched" column; mockup2 is B2:B9 in the given sample.
However, it fails when there's not an exact match found, using "TRUE" seems to break the other ones that are working fine.

What I'm looking to achieve should look like below:

[image]

A few things to note, is that the full data contains more identifiers which are different from what is shown in the sample. The only thing that shows up in multiple identifiers is `-C`, an example of more identifiers would be `BLK, CDAS, BLK S, BLK A, KYUIS-C, KYUOXAR T` etc.

Is there a way to achieve what I want with Excel?

Comment: You don't show the column letters or row numbers in your screenshot, so we don't know what  "B3" refers to. If the second screenshot is the output, where is the input for the formula? What is the input for the results in the Matched column?

Comment: @teylyn Changed the sample data to contain all information. The second screenshots is my desired output, what I'm trying to get. There's no formula there, just manually added what I wanted Matched column to look like.

Comment: I don't understand the desired outcome. Based on your second screenshot, the lookup term in the third row is `ALB-C P/E` and the desired result for that lookup is `ALB-C P` - Can you explain the logic?  If your lookup term is from current row column A and your desired result is what you have written, how can the lookup return be from column B? If you lookup A2 in column A and return the value from the found row, that is by definition the same row. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: I want to match the value in the "Identifier" column to the closest/exact match in "MyIdent" column. Like I already mentioned vlookup doesn't do this. That's why I asked if I can achieve this somehow.

Comment: So, what does "mockup2" in your Vlookup refer to? Column B? Why use Vlookup when you only look in one column? Vlookup is used to return a value from another column for a match. By definition. That's what "lookup" means. Otherwise it would be called "match", which is also a function. Also, when you use text, you cannot return an approximate match. It doesn't work this way. There is no way to match "ALB-C P" when you search for "ALB-C P/E" .  [...continued...]

Comment: .... and a wildcard is used to substitute MISSING letters. You can't add a * to "ALB-C P/E" and then expect to find a text that has fewer characters than the search string. It would work the other way around, i.e. you could match and return `ALB-C P/E` if you search for `ALB-C P*`

Comment: What you are after is not doable with Excel formulas, since you want to do something like a fuzzy match. You need code for that. Take a look at this for some enlightenment https://www.excel-university.com/perform-approximate-match-and-fuzzy-lookup-in-excel/

Comment: I see what misc15 is trying to match.

Comment: He wants to search for the longest value in column B matching the whole of, or part of the value in column 1. Realising this in a formula seems hard. Match and sorry length would be my hunch and then check the first match that has a 100% match for all characters in column B for the same length + wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

https://photos.app.goo.gl/tmRJfQK6DM2Hu7nYA

`=IFERROR(INDEX(SORTBY($B$2:$B$9,LEN($B2:$B9),-1),MATCH(1,(LEFT(A2,LEN(SORTBY($B$2:$B$9,LEN($B$2:$B$9),-1)))=SORTBY($B$2:$B$9,LEN($B$2:$B$9),-1))*(SORTBY($B$2:$B$9,LEN($B$2:$B$9),-1)=LEFT(A2,LEN(SORTBY($B$2:$B$9,LEN($B$2:$B$9),-1)))),0)),"")`

I don't know if it's to be entered as an array function (`ctrl + shift + enter`, since SORTBY is an array function already, but my version of excel does not support this yet. This is available in Office 365.

I sorted the data by length manually in the snipe, but I think the sortby will work without having to pet the data.

Let me know if it works for you.